# Variable driven timeframe in request.security() compiles one way and fails in another

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to work around the simple string requirement of the timeframe parameter of request.security() and the fact that it compiles in one scenario yet fails in another makes no sense to me.

I've successfully used a variable assignment in if() statements and it compiles, but as soon as I put a non-simple variable in those if statements, even though the variable in the if statement has nothing to do with the call to request.security, it fails.  This makes no sense.  I've put comments in the code snippet below which explain that only changing ONE LINE of code is the difference between success and failure.  I hope someone can help me find a way to do this, or at least an explanation that makes sense.

here is the code that compiles, with comments showing the one line of code swap which causes it to fail saying a simple string is required in request.security():

```
var int higherTFOffset = input.int(0,"Higher TF",[0,1,2,3],tooltip = "# of Higher Timeframes to use, 0=Current Chart",group = "EMA Period Settings")
var int ema1Period = input.int(6,"EMA1 Periods",tooltip = "# of Periods for first EMA",group = "EMA Period Settings")


// array of possible timeframes to use based on current chart timeframe
var tfArray = array.new<string>(1,"1")
array.push(tfArray,"5")
array.push(tfArray,"15")
array.push(tfArray,"1H")
array.push(tfArray,"4H")
array.push(tfArray,"D")
array.push(tfArray,"W")
array.push(tfArray,"M")

// get the array index that matches the current chart timeframe
var curTFElement = array.indexof(tfArray,timeframe.period)
if(curTFElement == -1 or curTFElement + higherTFOffset > 7)
    higherTFOffset := 0

// this is the var actually used in the request.security() call
var tfToUse = "1"

/// if I comment the next line and uncomment the line after, it fails to compile
/// but calcTF has nothing to do with the request.security() call
/// and in either case the variable tfToUse is getting reassigned
var calcTF = "5"
//var calcTF = array.get(tfArray,curTFElement + higherTFOffset)

if(calcTF == "1")
    tfToUse := "1"
if(calcTF == "5")
    tfToUse := "5"
else 
    tfToUse := timeframe.period

ema1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,tfToUse,ta.ema(close,ema1Period))
```

This situation is patently ridiculous.  I've also tried creating a user defined function that takes a series string and returns the value string(tfToUse) and that doesn't work either.

```
seriesToSimple(myString) =>
    string(myString)
```

I was expecting there must be some way to convert the variable type to simple string, or, avoid the problem by putting in if()s that are controlled by a different variable irrelevant to the request.security() function

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `array.get()` will always return a `series string` type variable, even if you use `string()` or `str.tostring()`.

This will also apply to any variable declarations done by using it (even in if statements), so your `tfToUse` variable is getting converted into a `series string` as well.

As of now, Pine Script does not allow conversion of `series string` to `simple string`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I really appreciate it.
Needless to say, this is extremely irritating lol....

Comment: Indeed, pine-script feels incredibly limited at times.